# javascript, split string and show one word bold

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a string with the index of the word that I want to show it bold.

```
this.splitSentence(exercise.sentence,boldWordIndex)
```

so I decided to split the string into 3 parts; before boldWord, boldWord and after that.
so I defined the function as follow. but I have a problem in join that at 3 words in the middle have no space. and also I think there should be a better way.

```
splitedSentence(sentence,index) {
        var splitedSentece = sentence.split(" ");
        var slice1=splitedSentece.slice(0,index);
        var slice2=splitedSentece.slice(index,index+1);
        var slice3=splitedSentece.slice(index+1,splitedSentece.length);
        return [slice1.join(" "),slice2.join(" "),slice3.join(" ")];
}
```

obs! I am writing this in a react app

Comment: This helps you? this.html(this.text().replace('word','<b>word</b>'));

Comment: I do not know the word (value), I just have the index (number), this is what the server provides. an object which contains the sentence string and the index of the word.

Comment: here's an idea - https://jsfiddle.net/jaromanda/gec1xy7o/

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks but as I mentioned I do not know the value of the word , I just have the index. there might be several occurrences of the same word in the sentence but only that index is important for me

Comment: yeah, the `var trigger` is for demo purposes, it could be populated any way you want - if that code is too difficult to understand, then good luck

Comment: @JaromandaX no the code is simple, but my problem was "several occurrences of the same word".  thanks anyway it was a good hint

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what are you looking for >> [**`fiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/1475/):

```
class Example extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
        word: ''
    }
    this.change = this.change.bind(this) ;
  }
  change(e){
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value});
  }
  render(){
    const index = this.props.sentences.split(' ').indexOf(this.state.word);
    const sentences = this.props.sentences.split(' ').map((item, key) => {
        // index may come from server   
        return <Word classN={index === key ? 'foo' : ''} key={key} text={item} />
    });

    return <div>
        <input name='word' type='text' onChange={this.change}/> <br/>
            {sentences}
    </div>
  }
}

class Word extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return <span className={this.props.classN}>{` ${this.props.text} `}</span>
  }
}

React.render(<Example sentences={'Hello World from ReactJS'}/>, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: thanks a lot, this is handy for another part of my project, but I am sorry that can not mark it is the answer. cause I wanted it to be an exportable function in another folder, as simple as possible, and mapping + another component makes it a bit complicated. but thanks again.